# no operator ">>" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::istream >> const double

Tags: c++

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m8gt.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define Pi 3.14159
 
using namespace std;
 
class Rectangle
{
    public:
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output,const Rectangle &D)
        {
            output<<"length:"<<D.length<<endl<<"height:"<<D.height<<endl;
            return output;
        }
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &input,const Rectangle &D)
        {
            input >> D.length >> D.height;
            return input;
        }
    private:
        double length;
        double height;
};
```

The error is in [17,19]:no operator ">>" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::istream >> const double

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: You don't declare a variable as `const &` which you want to write values to.

Comment: `const Rectangle &D` means you cannot modify `D` or its members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself, can you **read** into a const variable? Reading to a variable changes the variable, so the answer is obviously no.

Try this

```
friend istream &operator>>(istream &input,Rectangle &D)
```